# GNU make: expansion of a deferred construct

Tags: gnu-make, variable-expansion

On [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) site containing the documentation describing how `make` reads a `Makefile`, there is the following paragraph:

> [...]
>
> It’s important to understand this two-phase approach because it has a direct impact on how variable and function expansion happens; this is often a source of some confusion when writing makefiles. Here we will present a summary of the phases in which expansion happens for different constructs within the makefile. We say that expansion is immediate if it happens during the first phase: in this case make will expand any variables or functions in that section of a construct as the makefile is parsed. We say that expansion is deferred if expansion is not performed immediately. Expansion of a deferred construct is not performed until **either the construct appears later in an immediate context**, or until the second phase.
>
> [...]

I do not know what the highlighted part means.

Does it try to say that if there is a variable reference first found in a `deferred` section it will not be expanded during the first phase, but if the same variable reference is then found (later in the `Makefile`) in an `immediate` context, that variable reference will be expanded? Why would it say this explicitly?

Or does it try to say that there are cases when the exact same line can be read within a different context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not know what the highlighted part means.
>
> Does it try to say that if there is a variable reference first found
>   in a `deferred` section it will not be expanded during the first phase,
>   but if the same variable reference is then found (later in the
>   `Makefile`) in an `immediate` context, that variable reference will be
>   expanded?

Something like this, but I hesitate to say "yes" because I'm not sure I fully understand *you*.  Instead, I put it in my own words: the manual says that an expression with a deferred expansion is expanded immediately when it is evaluated as part of the value of an expression that is immediately expanded.  Example:

```
INTRO     := The messages are
DEFERRED   = $(MESSAGE1) literal message
IMMEDIATE := $(INTRO) $(DEFERRED)
MESSAGE1   = deferred message,

demo:
    @echo immediate: "$(IMMEDIATE)"
    @echo deferred: "$(INTRO) $(DEFERRED)"
```

Demo:

> ```
> $ make demo
> immediate: The messages are  literal message
> deferred: The messages are deferred message, literal message
> $
> ```

Note that variable `DEFERRED` is expanded immediately as part of the process of setting the value of immediately-expanded variable `IMMEDIATE`.  You can see this from the difference in the output of the two `echo` commands.  You can also see that this expansion does not stick to `DEFERRED`, which is one of the things that can be confusing.

> Why would it say this explicitly?

Because one might suppose otherwise.  Specifically, one might suppose that building the "demo" target in the example above would cause two identical lines to be printed. That would require a deferred expansion of `DEFERRED` being somehow symbolically encoded into the immediate expansion of `IMMEDIATE`, or else that `DEFERRED` be somehow converted into an immediately-expanded variable.  Nothing along those lines happens.

Note, too, that the two expansions of `DEFERRED` are different in this case, which is not necessarily a possibility that is immediately evident.

> Or does it try to say that there are cases when the exact same line
>   can be read within a different context?

Inasmuch as I differentiate between *identical* and *exact same*, the only way "the exact same" line can be evaluated in different contexts is if it is part of the expansion of a deferred-expansion expression.  Then it can appear in both immediate and deferred context, as the text `$(MESSAGE1) literal message` in the example does.  In that sense, yes, the manual is talking about that; it's not different from your other alternative.

It is also possible for distinct but identical text to appear in different contexts, but this is not as interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example, the expansion of the value of the variable DEFERRED is not done immediately (when it is first read). I'm trying to match the manual text with this example. Therefore, in "the construct appears later in an immediate context", "the construct" is the variable DEFERRED and the immediate context is the value of the "immediate variable" IMMEDIATE? Also, in your last sentence, what do you mean by "distinct but identical text"?

Comment: Yes, "the construct" is the expansion of variable `DEFERRED`.  It appears (by reference) in immediate context in the expansion of variable `IMMEDIATE`.  Distinct but identical text: I like pizza.  I like pizza.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. However, in my opinion, the terminology could be better. In the same paragraph there are mentions of "expansions of [...] in a section of a construct", "**standalone** constructs" and "deferred constructs". I believe this could be rephrased using variables, expressions and statements (e.g. variable assignments). Thank you again.

Comment: @user42768, you are welcome.  As for terminology, be aware that GCC supports more kinds of constructs than variables.  Function calls, for one.  The wording is a bit awkward, I agree, but it is written to cover multiple related cases.